# onPageSizeChange in react gives old value

Tags: reactjs, react-table

while I am trying to change the number of rows, let's say from 20 rows to 25 rows, I am getting old data on row change.Instead of 25, I am getting 20.

```
  <ReactTable filterable columns={this.getTableColumns()} data={items} showPagination ={true}
                 onPageChange={this.onPageChange} defaultPageSize={5} onPageSizeChange={(pageSize,pageIndex) => {
                    this.setState({ pageSize});
                    alert("this.state.pageSize" + this.state.pageSize);
                  }}
```

On page change from 20 to 25, I am getting pagesize as 20 but I want the current selected pagesize

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to this code:

```
this.setState({ pageSize});
alert("this.state.pageSize" + this.state.pageSize);
```

it is because `setState` is asynchronous. And in the `alert` you won't see the latest value immediately.

Answer (score 0):

From [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

so u can do it like 
`this.setState({pageSize}, () => alert("this.state.pageSize" + this.state.pageSize);)`